# Graphics performance decrease after inserting two non SLI GPU's for three Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I recently was given a third monitor. So I left my two monitors that I already had connected to my 9800 GTX and added a 6100 Geforce video card for my third monitor.

I now have extremely slow graphics on all monitors. The one connected to the 6100 even slower.

So slow that some of the text that I am writing doesn't show up until after a few milliseconds. Dragging a window around is very jerky.

I have all most up to date drivers for both cards. One monitor is 22 inches and the other two are 15 inch full screen ones.

Is this what I should expect? Is there no fix? Is there another solution? Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Is the 22 inch monitor the new monitor?

Comment: Also, which OS architecture (32 or 64 bit) is the OS?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit. No the monitor is one of the small 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your power supply might not be up to snuff for that much video card...I would check the wattage rating on the PSU.  You can get poor or inconsistent performance when just scraping by and not getting all the juice you need to your video cards.

Comment: -1 because??????

Comment: Hmm interesting. I mean I have a 650 watt psu. That should be enough right? I have 4 hdd and a 1 water pump. Nothing else but fans... When I look at my backup battery software it tells me I am only using 277 watts.. Thanks for you input (not sure who -1 u)

Comment: 650 should be enough.  i have had an issue with a 500 watt psu pushing 2 video cards that got sluggish/buggy/crashy and going up to 750W fixed it.  it was a legitimate concern though

Comment: Just saw my backup battery software complain that i was drawing to much power. Maybe I have to many devices on it. I will try taking some off in the morning!

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue :( I moved my computer's power directly to my wall outlet.

Comment: +1 because I agree that the PSU might be the problem - it should be sufficient but it might be performing under spec.  It's also possible there's actually something WRONG with the card you added...

Comment: got a chance to unplug some HDD and now she is fast again! Thanks!